# Is the Steam remote downloading feature gone?

Tags: steam

My desktop client is online and running. I visit my games library through the Steam Community website and the Android Steam app and there is no "Install" button on any game.

I haven't found any news regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This document](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5085-SCBN-1521) about Steam Remote Downloads explains all the limitations(or it should). The only one that you may face is start an install from the Steam Mobile App.

Altough, it seems that you are compliant with those so, you may need to ask this to the Steam support guys if there is anything else you need to configure. There are threads with the same issue at Steam forums, and non of them seems to have a solution.

Open a support ticket or try to change browser. This is the best you can do.

**Steam Forums:**

- [Can't install a game remotely.](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864972399731855364/)
- [Remote download not working](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/882964580393276588/)

Answer (score 1):

I have an updated answer, emphasis added:

> In order to initiate a remote download you need to **make sure that you**
>   **are logged into your Steam account on the computer you wish to have**
>   **your game installed on.**
>
> After this you need to do the following to download a game:
>
> - **Login to your Steam account via http://www.steamcommunity.com**
> - **Click on Games**
> - **Click on All Games**
> - **Locate the game you wish to download and click on the download button**
>
> You will be able to see the progress of the download until it is
>   complete. Once finished you will be able to return to your PC and play
>   your game.

(https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5085-SCBN-1521)

More details, emphasis added:

> Remote Downloads are enabled from any web browser when you leave the
>   Steam application running on your PC or Mac. Of course, we only
>   recommend you do this on your own private, secured computer.
>
> When you’re logged into Steam on your home PC or Mac, you can manage
>   your library by visiting your Games list on the web.
>
> - **Log into your Steam account online from your computer**
>     **or mobile device at www.steampowered.com**
> - **Visit your Games list by clicking on your Steam persona**
>     **at the top of the page, and then clicking Games in the**
>     **secondary navigation bar.**
>     Please filter for All Games. If you’re logged into the Steam client,
>     the games list will reflect the installation state of your library on
>     that machine.
> - **Locate your game and tap the install button to initiate your remote download.**
>
> You may choose to refresh this page to check the current status of
>   your installation. When you return to your active client session, your
>   game will be ready to play!

(https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6324-IGHC-5301)

I did this and it started working immediately. So the URL's I visited were like:

- https://steamcommunity.com
- https://steamcommunity.com/id/...
- https://steamcommunity.com/id/.../games/?tab=all

Then next to each game listed was this button, which you click to install:

[image: Button Image]